# Python: Importing subprocess modules from v3.3 to v2.7.4

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, future

I want to import `subprocess` module from py v3.3 to v2.7 to be able to use the `timeout` functionality.

After reading few posts I tried this

```
from __future__ import subprocess
```

But it says:

```
SyntaxError: future feature subprocess is not defined
```

Then I found out that future doesn't have any feature `subprocess`.

So where and how should I import the `subprocess` from v3.3?

Comment: There is a backport: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/subprocess32

Comment: What's wrong with the 2.7 version? (Generally, you're not going to be able to use features from a new version in an old one. If you could, the new version wouldn't exist; it'd be the same as the old version. `__future__` is for gradual introduction of backwards-incompatible changes.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the backport is a good idea. Here is a comparison of `subprocess.call`. Note that having the named parameter `timeout` after `*popenargs` is a syntax error in Python2, so the backport has a workaround. The timeout parameter for the other functions is handled similarly. You should look at the `wait` method of `Popen` if you are interested in how the timeout is actually implemented.

### Python2.7 subprocess

```
def call(*popenargs, **kwargs):
    """Run command with arguments.  Wait for command to complete, then
    return the returncode attribute.

    The arguments are the same as for the Popen constructor.  Example:

    retcode = call(["ls", "-l"])
    """
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
```

### Python3.3 subprocess

```
def call(*popenargs, timeout=None, **kwargs):
    """Run command with arguments.  Wait for command to complete or
    timeout, then return the returncode attribute.

    The arguments are the same as for the Popen constructor.  Example:

    retcode = call(["ls", "-l"])
    """
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
        try:
            return p.wait(timeout=timeout)
        except:
            p.kill()
            p.wait()
            raise
```

### Python2.7 subprocess32 backport

```
def call(*popenargs, **kwargs):
    """Run command with arguments.  Wait for command to complete or
    timeout, then return the returncode attribute.

    The arguments are the same as for the Popen constructor.  Example:

    retcode = call(["ls", "-l"])
    """
    timeout = kwargs.pop('timeout', None)
    p = Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs)
    try:
        return p.wait(timeout=timeout)
    except TimeoutExpired:
        p.kill()
        p.wait()
        raise
```

Comment: Unfortunately, backporting doesn't work in Windows (for various reasons). Cross-compilation with tools such as MinGW may make it possible to use it but I'm still at a loss since it fixes a ton of bugs but the official URL about subprocess32 states that it provides support only for POSIX-compliant systems.